# oauth.io linkedin gives 403 error, when the same code used to work fine

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi, oauth.io

Looks like Linkedin or oauth.io changed something recently.

Used to connect fine, and now it's giving an 403 error.

Checked also on the oauth.io site with my app settings, and it gives the same error when trying to connect using the "Try Oauth" button:

```
Connection failed with linkedin
We received an error while we were trying to authorize you. It can come from     your API Keys or your provider app settings.

This error was returned by the server:

Error during the 'request_token' step (HTTP status code: 403)
```

The Linkedin App interface seem to have changed:

- reentered whitelists
- reentered oauth 2.0 link
- reentered my info, etc. looks like it is setup correct
- this setup used to work until recently

This is the code:

```
OAuth.initialize('xxxxx');

OAuth.popup('linkedin')
.done(function(result) {

    console.log("Connecting to Linkedin");

    result.me()
    .done(function (response) {

        //            

    })
    .fail(function (err) {

        alert("Problem connecting to Linkedin: " + err);
    });

})
.fail(function (err) {

    alert("Problem connecting to Linkedin: " + err);
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: using the phonegap+javascript api, but the problem seem to be also in the  oauth.io console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On February 12th 2015 LinkedIn announced a series of changes to their developer program.  These changes have now begun to take affect and will be rolled out to the entire LinkedIn application base between May 12th - May 19th, 2015.

Please read with following URLs

https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/apply-with-linkedin

**Note-** If you are requesting for `r_fullprofile` or `r_contactinfo` permission then you have to read apply for linked in terms and condition on apply with linked-in page.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, with help from `oauth.io`:

Check this link: https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition

Linkedin has made some changes to their API which can lead to a 403 error if you're using the `r_fullprofile` or `r_contactinfo` permission without having applied to the linkedin Companies API.